# Normalizing CDF in Python

Tags: python-3.x, cdf, normalizing

I want to calculate and plot the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a given sample, new_dO18 and then overlay the CDF of a normal distribution with a given mean and standard deviation on the same plot. I am having problems normalizing the CDF. I should have values ranging between 0 and 1 on the x axis. Can someone guide me as to where I went wrong. I'm sure it's a simple fix but I'm very new to Python. I've included my steps so far. Thanks!

```
# Use np.histogram to get counts in each bin. See the help page or
# documentation on how to use this function, and what it returns.

# normalize the data new_dO18 using a for loop
norm_newdO18 = []
for element in new_dO18:
    x = element 
    y = (x - np.mean(new_dO18))/np.std(new_dO18)
    norm_newdO18.append(y)
print ('normalized dO18 values, excluding outliers:', norm_newdO18)
print()

# Use the histogram function to bin the data
num_bins = 20
counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(norm_newdO18, bins=num_bins,   normed=0)

# Calculate and plot CDF of sample 
cdf = np.cumsum(counts)
scale = 1.0/cdf[-1]
norm_cdf = scale * cdf

plt.plot(bin_edges[1:], norm_cdf, label = 'dO18 values')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), loc='upper left', ncol=1)
plt.xlabel('normalized dO18 data')
plt.ylabel('frequency')

# Calculate and overlay the CDF of a normal distribution with sample mean and std
# as parameters.

# specific normally distributed function with mean and st. dev 
mu, sigma = np.mean(new_dO18), np.std(new_dO18) 
norm_theoretical = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)

# Calculate and plot CDF of theoretical sample 
counts1, bin_edges1 = np.histogram(norm_theoretical, bins=20, normed=0)
cdft= np.cumsum(counts1)
scale = 1.0/cdft[-1]
norm_cdft = scale * cdf
plt.plot(bin_edges[1:], norm_cdft, label = 'theoretical values')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), loc='upper left', ncol=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why not just use a discrete random variable in SciPy? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html

Comment: Also (since we don't have access to your data), what's the max of the CDF after you attempt to normalize it?

Comment: the max CDF after I attempt to normalize is 2.5

Comment: Wait, the bin widths aren't 1, are they? There's your culprit...

Comment: Incidentally, you can step around all of this by setting `density=True` in your call to `np.histogram` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy-histogram